# Want to reduce speed of rotation smoothly while moving sprite to a point

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using COCOS-2D. I want to reduce the speed of rotation of sprite with object movement towards destination.

Initially the speed is faster, i want to reduce it smoothly with movement.

Please help how can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to run two actions in parallel - one for movement and another for rotation. Since you want your rotation to gradually slowdown, it could be done by applying an ease action on top of the rotation action. Something along these lines:

```
float animDuration = 1.5f;
float animRotateAngle = 720.f; // deg
CCActionInterval* effect = [CCSpawn actions: 
     [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration: animDuration position: destPoint], 
     [CCEaseSineOut actionWithAction: [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration: animDuration angle:animRotateAngle]], 
      nil];

[object runAction: effect];
```

Comment: But how to decrease speed of rotation along with movement .

Comment: Add easing out to both actions and thats it)

Answer (score 0):

[Create a series of rotations](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/embedded/cocos2d-x/d9/df5/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_rotate_to.html#a6f154b202f82674f47aff85132021bb6), either explicitly or programmatically, increasing the duration and/or decreasing the angle with each new rotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)update:(CCTime)delta {

// reduce _ship.rotation
[_ship.physicsBody applyTorque:(_ship.rotation - rotation_01)*800];
rotation_01 = _ship.rotation;

}
```